# Pandas select next x rows in dataframe without iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dftrial = pd.DataFrame({'col 1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'],
                        'col 2': [1, -1, -2, -3, 2, -1, 1, 5, 6, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1]})
dftrial
```

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe that identifies where `col 2` is positive,  then take that row AS WELL AS the next x rows (in this case, just the next row) below that, and then delete the duplicates.

I am able to do such a thing using `iterrows`, as shown here.

```
storage = []
for index, row in dftrial.iterrows():
    if row['col 2'] > 0:
        savethis = dftrial[index : index + 2]
        storage.append(savethis)
        
result = pd.concat(storage)
result.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
display(result)
```

Which results in the table I want:

[image]

However, I'm running this code on a dataframe that has hundreds of thousands of rows. Running `iterrows` by definition goes through every row, making this process slow. Is there a faster way to run this code? I understand there are existing pages that offer alternatives to iterrows, but none of them seem to explain how I could use it to select rows below it.

The closest I've gotten is by using a `lambda` function, as shown below, but the function only takes the rows where col 2 is greater than zero and does not include the following rows. I've been stuck trying to get the indexing of rows right, and any help would be appreciated.

```
dftrial[dftrial.apply(lambda x: x['col 2'] > 0, axis = 1)]
```

Comment: Why is the line with index "2" not in your expected results? It's the second line below a positive number in `col 2`, and it is not duplicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To produce your example, which isn't quite the same as per the description:

```py
>>> dftrial.loc[(dftrial['col 2'] > 0).rolling(2, min_periods=0).max() > 0]
   col 1  col 2
0      a      1
1      b     -1
4      e      2
5      f     -1
6      g      1
7      h      5
8      i      6
9      j     -2
13     n      1
```

If instead we go strictly by your description ("the *next* two columns"), then:

```py
>>> dftrial.loc[(dftrial['col 2'] > 0).rolling(
...     2, min_periods=0, closed='left').max() > 0]
   col 1  col 2
1      b     -1
2      c     -2
5      f     -1
6      g      1
7      h      5
8      i      6
9      j     -2
10     k     -2
```

**Explanation**

The key, of course, is to start by identifying the rows where `col 2` is positive:

```py
>>> dftrial.assign(ispos=dftrial['col 2'] > 0)
   col 1  col 2  ispos
0      a      1   True
1      b     -1  False
2      c     -2  False
3      d     -3  False
4      e      2   True
5      f     -1  False
6      g      1   True
7      h      5   True
8      i      6   True
9      j     -2  False
10     k     -2  False
11     l     -2  False
12     m     -2  False
13     n      1   True
```

Then we use `rolling().max()` to "bleed" that truth to the next two rows (unfortunately, `Rolling` doesn't have `.any()`, otherwise we would use that instead of `.max() > 0`):

```py
>>> dftrial.assign(
...     ispos=dftrial['col 2'] > 0,
...     mask=(dftrial['col 2'] > 0).rolling(
...         2, min_periods=0, closed='left').max() > 0,
... )
   col 1  col 2  ispos   mask
0      a      1   True  False
1      b     -1  False   True
2      c     -2  False   True
3      d     -3  False  False
4      e      2   True  False
5      f     -1  False   True
6      g      1   True   True
7      h      5   True   True
8      i      6   True   True
9      j     -2  False   True
10     k     -2  False   True
11     l     -2  False  False
12     m     -2  False  False
13     n      1   True  False
```

Then, it's just a matter of selecting the rows with that mask.